# Can't pass path to shell script

Tags: mac-osx, bash, shell-scripting

I'm new to OSX, and don't use the commandline that often. I'm trying to use a script to do some automatic deployment, but when I execute the script it is looking for a directory.

I tried:

```
sh myscript.sh '/Users/profiles/Desktop/Development'
sh myscript.sh /Users/profiles/Desktop/Development
sh myscript.sh -/Users/profiles/Desktop/Development
```

but I keep getting "No Such file or directory". What is the proper way to do this?

I know this is a basic question, but I can't seem to find a simple answer. Everything I find on google is much more advanced..

UPDATE:
In the script, it's looking for the path like this:

```
DIR_DEVELOP=$@

if [ -z $DIR_DEVELOP ]; then
    echo "Syntax: myscript.sh <destination>"
    exit 1
```

Comment: Also, what's in your shebang line ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix) )?

Comment: looks like "!#/bin/bash

Comment: Then you don't need to pass the script to `sh` (which is itself a shell) at all as the purpose of the shebang line is to choose an interpreter for the script. Assuming the script has the execute bit set, you can call it like `./myscript.sh '/Users/profiles/Desktop/Development'`.

Comment: Perhaps another good question for us to ask of you would be *Please show us what your script does when it looks for the path you pass*, because the bug is probably there. I should have started with that question :)

Comment: @msanford - This is a script that has been in operation for a while, so I know it's not the script, it's me...

Comment: @msanford - ./myscript.sh '/Users/profiles/Desktop/Development' still says "No Such File or Directory"

Comment: What I meant by my second comment was: would you please post the source code of your script that relates to your path argument (probably a `{$1}` somewhere) just to check.

Comment: I added that part to my question...

Comment: Can you post output of `ls -l myscript.sh` Since you are not reporting seeing any output from `sh -x ...` I'm wondering if the script isn't in the current directory, or maybe there is a problem with the filename such as containing a trailing space character.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable tracing in bash:

```
bash -x myscript.sh '/Users/profiles/Desktop/Development'
```

You will see the "No Such file or directory" message right after the line that generates the error.

Comment: I ran that line and got the same thing...

Comment: It is the same output? Or the same error?

Comment: Same exact output - just says "No Such File or Directory"

Comment: Before the error can you see commands from the script? Is the partition mounted with no-exec?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `'` in your path. According to the [Advanced Bash Scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#APPREF):

> $@
>   Same as $*, but each parameter is a quoted string, that is, the parameters are passed on intact, without interpretation or expansion. This means, among other things, that each parameter in the argument list is seen as a separate word.

So the path your script is trying to access is literally `'/Users/profiles/Desktop/Development'` instead of `/Users/profiles/Desktop/Development`